# getting BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_DEVELOPER_ERROR from a live app

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

Hopefully someone has an idea here, we have a app out in the wild, taking about 30-50 in-app purchases a day without a problem. occasionally, at least once every other day, we get an error message from the users phone 5:Developer Error (I am using IabHelper)

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's known that Google's IabHelper have many bugs (for exemple it's using AsyncTasks..)

Maybe you can try this library:
https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3

Comment: FYI is doing exactly the same also using AsyncTask.